# How can we create new/custom service in OpenStack other than including services of OpenStack?

Tags: openstack

I have created the OpenStack private cloud and I want to add my custom service into it, but I didn't find any provision to include it.

Could you please guide me on this.
Is there any provision to creating new/custom service in OpenStack?
There are 46 services but I want to create my own service for some other provision
so can anybody tell me about that?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. What sort of service? What have you tried so far?